# WKURLSchemeHandler delegate doesn't get called during evaluateJavascript

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, wkwebview, wkurlschemehandler

I am loading local html file which will load first and then I will have to load an image that is also available locally only after the html is loaded fully. So, I am setting src for the image tag using id and evaluateJavascript. WKURLSchemeHander delegate is not called when this evaluateJavascript is loaded. It is called only when loadFile or loadHTMLString is called. How do I make this delegate get called during evaluateJavascript function and load the image on to WKWebview?

```
 let js = "document.getElementById('image-id').setAttribute('src', '\(imageURL)');"
```

Comment: Facing the same problem since iOS 14, did you find something relevant about this? Thanks.